# Getting an element inside an #id element - Angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have

```
const saveBtnElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#save-user');
console.log(saveBtnElement);
```

where I can see in `console` of karma tests :

```
<my-button _ngcontent-c0="" id="save-user" _nghost-c3="" ng-reflect-disabled="true" ng-reflect-classnames="primary">
<button _ngcontent-c3="" class="my-button primary" ng-reflect-ng-class="my-button primary" disabled="">

    <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": ""
}-->

    <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
    <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}-->
    <span _ngcontent-c3="">
        Save &amp; Close
    </span>
```

I want to check the disabled property of my button by using something like

```
expect(saveBtnElement.hasAttribute('disabled')).toBeTruthy();
```

How to get the `<button>` which is inside inside my another component `my-button` ??

Comment: You can simply select `#save-user > button`

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner : Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As provided by Bunyamin:

```
const saveBtnElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#save-user > button');
```

did the trick.